# How to update iframe page tab content using a form?

Tags: post, facebook-iframe

I am trying to pass data using a form to a Facebook iFrame page tab but can't seem to figure how to do it.

I have a page tab on my Facebook page with several elements such as links and images directing users to various pages on the main website. This is updated every week, so rather than update the HTML file and upload via FTP everyweek  i would like to see if i can create a form to pass the new data to the iframe.

In addition the Facebook page tab cannot be created in PHP as the server is running ASP.NET

I am trying to do this without the use of a database table if possible, using POST or GET would be preferable.

If anyone knows of any tutorials or has any tips i would be very grateful.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass content or interact with iframe content if it's on the same domain as the parent webpage that has the iframe.  All browsers have a "same origin policy" that prevent you from being able to do that - sorry :(

Comment: Hi Losbear, yeah i was thinking that would be the case. I can easily pass data from one page to another within the website, but once i place the page inside Facebook's iframe it doesnt pull the data.